# How to match the at least number？

Tags: php

I have an input area as shown. Since the price is at least, I don't know how to enter this price for database matching.

```
<?php
$type = $_POST['type'];

$conn = mysqli_connect();   
$query = "select type, description, price from product where type = ?"; 
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($pStmt, $type_r, $description_r, $price_r);
```

Comment: `where price <= ?` with `"$dollar.$cents"`?

Comment: @Ireal edit and complete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query for (>= because you said price is at least) :

```
$query = "select type, description, price from product where type = ? and price >= ?";
```

and instantiate `$price` like so before `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($pStmt,'sd', $type, $price);`:

```
$price = $_POST["dollar"] . '.' . $_POST["cents"];
```

Comment: @Jamborn how you know inputs are "dollar" & "cents"?

Comment: Author didn't specify them so I used those names as example.